# grub-mkconfig generates duplicate entries for an Ubuntu/Gentoo dual boot setup

Tags: ubuntu, grub2, dual-boot, gentoo

I'm currently running Ubuntu (Xubuntu, specifically) as the primary OS on one of my systems. I've been building up a Gentoo installation on a new logical volume on the same system and I'm at the point of creating the Grub configuration to allow me to switch between the two OSes at boot time.

From my understanding, the generated config should only show the following entries:

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu

  - Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic
  - Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic (recovery mode)
- Gentoo
- Advanced options for Gentoo

  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.18.11-gentoo
  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.18.11-gentoo (recovery mode)
- Memtest86
- Memtest86 (serial console 115200)

Trying this from the original Ubuntu installation, I get the following `grub.cfg` file: http://pastebin.com/sHkwSYdu

- Ubuntu
- Advanced options for Ubuntu

  - Ubuntu, with Linux 3.18.11-gentoo
  - Ubuntu, with Linux 3.18.11-gentoo (recovery mode)
  - Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic
  - Ubuntu, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic (recovery mode)
- Gentoo
- Advanced options for Gentoo

  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.18.11-gentoo
  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.18.11-gentoo (recovery mode)
  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic
  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic (recovery mode)
- Memtest86
- Memtest86 (serial console 115200)

Trying this from the Gentoo installation, I get the following `grub.cfg` file http://pastebin.com/uRLiEu9r:

- Gentoo
- Advanced options for Gentoo

  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.18.11-gentoo
  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.18.11-gentoo (recovery mode)
  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic
  - Gentoo, with Linux 3.13.0-48-generic (recovery mode)
- Memtest86
- Memtest86 (serial console 115200)

How can I configure `grub-mkconfig` to generate `grub.cfg` that includes the correct entries for the two OSes that I have installed on my HDD and doesn't duplicate entries?

Comment: Use Option 1: Create the Gentoo Volume as you have done, and then update-grub from the OS you want to be in charge of booting, in other words skip the section on configuring the bootloader in the handbook and update grub in XUbuntu